# NextJs passing in prop as className

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm having trouble with passing a prop to a className and am wondering if it is even possible.

For example, let's say `category` is passed into the function and `category` is `"category1"`. In the className can I call `styles.category` to get `styles.category1`?

```js
export const function ({category}) => {
    return (
      <button className={styles.category}></button>
    )
}
```

```css
.category1 {
    background: #FF4646 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    width:  200px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font: url('../../public/fonts/AirbnbCerealBlack.woff');
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:900;
    color: black;
}
    
.category2 {
    background: #4EEA9C 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    width:  270px;
    height: 270px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font: url('../../public/fonts/AirbnbCerealBlack.woff');
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:900;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as `styles[category]` to set the `className` on your button.

```js
export const function ({ category }) =>{
    return (
        <button className={styles[category]}></button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you unpack the argument, you should just be able to do `className={category}`.